# Cast HashMap<String, Integer> with HashMap<String, Double>

Tags: java

Why cast does not work in this case directly with

```
HashMap<String, Double> mapDouble = (HashMap<String, Integer>) mapInteger;
```

Is there an easier way than a loop ?

```
HashMap<String, Double> mapDouble;
for (Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry : mapInteger.entrySet()) {
    mapDouble.put(entry.getKey(), new Double(entry.getValue()) );
}
```

Comment: What do you think a cast does?

Comment: That's not how explicit casting works.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis don't know exactly how it works internally, but I think that it's just a type modification when the modification is possible.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but you need a loop! You have to go all the mapInteger to convert the values one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You could not cast the hashmap.

`entrySet()` will give better performance approach.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to use `Map<String, Number>`.

```
Map<String, Number> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    map.put(Integer.toString(i), i);
}
map.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " -> " + v.doubleValue()));
```